# Cannot open gnome-terminal ubuntu 15.10 (Bad Locale)

Tags: gnome-terminal, locale

Hello ubuntu community!

Recently i downloaded and installed ubuntu, and after some experimenting, im unable do open my terminal!

The problem occurred after i gave the machine the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install locales
```

Now i can only open xTerm, and i can't copy/paste from it...

I already tried to `apt-get purge gnome-terminal`/`apt-get install gnome-terminal`, but i was unsuccessful in repairing it!

Please, i need your help!

Edited:

This is the error i get when i try to execute `gnome-terminal` at xTerm:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallbac 'C' locale.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

Edit 2:
Yes, indeed it may be a Locale problem... But i don't know how to fix it yet!

After i run `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base` it says the package is already installed, but when i `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` it gives me the below perl error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_INDENTIFICATION = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "pt_BR.UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
are suported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you try to execute `gnome-terminal` from an xterm? are there any error messages? If so, please [edit] your question to include them.

Comment: Question edited!

Comment: @Jacs - It states that you have messed up your locales - `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base` .Type the command and see if it worked.

Comment: @Jacs - And then do this - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: @Raphael Still not working... After some searching i found that this is a common problem to many users, and there is no good site with enough SEO to satisfy fixing it quickly

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to fix this is regenerate the broken locale files. just do 
`sudo locale-gen`
and check if the file 
 
`/etc/default/locale`
has the following 2 definitions 

`LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US"`

are set possibly with other `LC_*` values for the Time , Numeric, Monetary types of the country you're in.